# Can't get the desired output of this binary search program in c language

Tags: arrays, c, function, error-handling, binary-search

We are required to make two functions, 1] Bubble Sort and 2] Binary Search. If an element doesn't belong to the array, the 2]nd function should return -1. In the main function we get the input and if the element does not lie in the array, we should print "Element not found". I have written the program according to the specifics that were asked in the question.

The 1]st function, Bubble Sort is working fine but 2]nd function is only giving "Element not found" as the output, no matter what the value. Please suggest a solution.

```
void bubbleSortDec(int arr[10])
{
    int i=0,j=0,temp=0;
    for(i=0;i<9;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<9-i;j++)
        {
            if(arr[j]<arr[j+1])
            {
                temp=arr[j];
                arr[j]=arr[j+1];
                arr[j+1]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

int binarySearch(int arr[10], int x)
{
    bubbleSortDec(arr);
    int first, last=0, middle=0;
    first = 0;
  last = 10 - 1;
  middle = (first+last)/2;

  while (first <= last) {
    if (arr[middle] < x)
      first = middle + 1;
    else if (arr[middle] == x) {
      printf("%d found at location %d.\n", x, middle+1);
      break;
    }
    else
      last = middle - 1;

    middle = (first + last)/2;
  }

  if (first > last)
    {
        return -1;
    }
 }   

int main()
{
        int arr[10];
        int i, x,k=0;
        printf("Enter 10 numbers \n");
        for(i=0; i<10;i++)
            {
                scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
            }
        printf("Enter a number to be searched \n");
        scanf("%d", &x);

            k=binarySearch(arr,x);
            if(k==-1)
                printf("Element not found \n");
    }
```

Comment: You sort the array in decreasing order, but the search is expecting it to be in increasing order.

Comment: Binary search requires sorted input, but calling bubble sort every time you look up an element in the array seems a little overcautious. And you probably want to return an index or so if the search is successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your bubble sort sorts the array in decreasing order. That is not a problem of course, you can still use in that way but you need to change your binary search. The problem is here.

Let's assume you have an array that is sorted in decreasing order and let's say you are searching for **17**.

```
65 54 32 17 9
```

Than you are looking for the midde element that is 32. In your code if the element that you are looking for is smaller than the middle element, you continue the search with the lower part of the array. But in this case it is wrong. Because the elements that are on the lower part of the array are bigger than the middle element. You need to look for the upper side of the array.

So you have two option.

**First** you can change your bubble sort to sort the array in increasing order.

```
void bubbleSortDec(int arr[10])
{
    int i=0,j=0,temp=0;
    for(i=0;i<9;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<9-i;j++)
        {
            if(arr[j]>arr[j+1]) // Change is here. (this "<" to this ">")
            {
                temp=arr[j];
                arr[j]=arr[j+1];
                arr[j+1]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Or** you can change your binary search to this.

```
int binarySearch(int arr[10], int x)
{
    bubbleSortDec(arr);
    int first, last=0, middle=0;
    first = 0;
  last = 10 - 1;
  middle = (first+last)/2;

  while (first <= last) {
    if (arr[middle] > x) // Change is here. (this "<" to this ">")
      first = middle + 1;
    else if (arr[middle] == x) {
      printf("%d found at location %d.\n", x, middle+1);
      /*
      Returning anything except "-1" is okey. Because you only check for "-1".
      */
      return middle;
    }
    else
      last = middle - 1;

    middle = (first + last)/2;
  }
  /*
  If you couldn't find the element in while loop that 
  means the element is not in the array. You don't need to check it again.
  */
  return -1;
 }
```

And **lastly** I wrote the same code in this way.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 10

void swap(int *i1, int *i2) {
    int temp = *i1;
    *i1 = *i2;
    *i2 = temp;
}

void bubbleSort(int arr[SIZE]) {
    
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < SIZE - i - 1; j++) {
            if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) swap(arr + j, arr + j + 1);
        }
    }
    
    return;
}

int binarySearch(int arr[SIZE], int x) {
    
    int first = 0, last = SIZE - 1;

    while (first <= last) {
        int middle = (first + last) / 2;

        if (arr[middle] == x) {
            return middle;
        } else if (x < arr[middle]) {
            last = middle - 1;
        } else {
            first = middle + 1;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}   

int main() {
    
    int arr[SIZE];
    printf("Enter %d numbers \n", SIZE);

    int i; for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) scanf("%d", arr + i);

    printf("Enter a number to be searched \n");
    int x;
    scanf("%d", &x);

    bubbleSort(arr);
    int k = binarySearch(arr, x);
    
    if (k == -1) printf("Element not found!\n");
    else printf("Element found at index %d.\n", k + 1);

    return 0;
}
```